# Angular reactive forms: Get form validity status only once

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

How can I subscribe to a form's statusChanges observable only once when the status is different from the previous one while the form's valueChanges is triggered?
The below subscription gets the status every time the form's value changes.

```
this.form.statusChanges
.subscribe(
    (status) => {
      console.log(status);
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used rxjs's distinctUntilChanged operator like below.

```
this.form.statusChanges
.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged()
)
.subscribe(
    (status) => {
      console.log(status);
    }
  );
```